# Remove LINE Account from Contact GroupConnect LINE Addresses Using Marketing Cloud API

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi, webhooks

If I use Marketing Cloud's Webhook (https://cl.s11.exct.net:443/Response_LineOriginated.ashx?channelId={channel id}) in my LINE Messaging API, a new contact is created whenever someone follows my Official LINE Account. This Contact contains the users LINE information and can contain multiple LINE accounts under the GroupConnect LINE Addresses attribute.

If the user unfollows my Official LINE Account, the LINE Account is removed from the Contact or the Contact itself is deleted altogether.

I want to do these functionalities using the Marketing Cloud API because I'm using my own Webhook.

I can handle the LINE follow functionality using Marketing Cloud API Create Contact
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/createContacts.htm

My question: 
Upon unfollow, how do I unlink a LINE Account from a Contact in Marketing Cloud using the Marketing Cloud API?